# How to filter of those special char from a word?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scala-2.8

I have

```
val content = "bala.ba* muthu.t@ jiang.xin="
```

How to filter of those junk char(*, @ & = ) in Scala?

For now I am using java substring, which may not the best for scala.

I also tried

```
filter (_ != "*" ) filter (_ != "@") filter (_ != "=")
```

Don't feel thats the right way

I would like to go with best functional way

Thanks in advance guys...

Comment: How about just:

    `scala> content.replaceAll("\\*|@","")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a `Set` and use it as function like this:

```
val specialChars = Set('*', '@', '&', '=')

val content = "bala.ba* muthu.t@ jiang.xin="
val res = content filterNot specialChars
// bala.ba muthu.t jiang.xin
```

Comment: @om-nom-nom: performance overhead or noise from `Set` creation?